# Unity3d Text Mesh Pro UGUI VS Text

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does Unity's Text Mesh Pro adds more performance to the app than using the plain UI.Text only?
I have been doing my research and I can't seem to find any article that explains if this is true and why.

Comment: The best way to have your answer is to test by yourself and use the profiler. Create a scene and put hundreds of TMP Texts, use the profiler and do the same with plain UI Text.

Comment: For a beginner myself I am not familiar with the profiler. Thanks I guess

Comment: Unity provides [nice tutorials on the subject](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/introduction-profiler)

Comment: For a beginner I'd recommend not worrying about performance too much, and just use whichever looks better. Once you get more familiar with everything it'll be far easier to profile performance and work out exactly which parts are really slowing things down.

Comment: Can't notice any practical performance hits. I can never go back to using the regular Text component though. TextMesh is just so much better at displaying text.

Answer (score 0):

I could never notice a performance drop when testing things with TextMesh Pro. It seems to be similar in cost to the regular Text. In general, I prefer using TextMesh Pro over the regular Text, simply because it's superior in functionality.